# Displaying Salesforce Information on Company Website

Tags: api

I have a request to create an API to show our Case information on our website (behind a log in page of course) but am unsure where to start. I'm being told I need to create the connection between the two but I've never connected Salesforce to something like this. If someone can point me the direction of a Trailhead I think I can work through it...I'm just not sure where to start.
Thanks!
A

Comment: One possible option: [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm)

Comment: I think the first question you need an answer for is how will authentication and Authorization be handled? Do you already have authenticated parts to your website? If so, are you using an Identity Provider that could be hooked up with Salesforce to support SSO? Etc. Getting hold of data after that is likely straight forward as per Victor L's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be able to get away with the standard APIs - meaning you don't have to build any new APIs; you can use the ones Salesforce already has available for accessing your objects.

Here's the [Lightning Platform API Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics) module to get you started on what's already available (and there's links included in the units for more resources, but [here's one for them](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)).  Here's the [Design Solutions with Salesforce APIs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/architect-solutions-with-the-right-api) trail which features that module.  It may be a bit overkill for your needs but doesn't hurt to have the link handy.

In the event that you do need something more complex, here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm) for creating APIs in Apex.